# "Я жду результаты тестирования" или "я жду результатов тестирования"?

Tags: согласование

На грамоте.ру задан вопрос: "Как правильно: "Я жду результаты тестирования" или "я жду результатов тестирования"?" Грамота.ру рекомендует второй вариант, но почему, не объясняет. А почему, собственно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С глаголами **ждать, хотеть, искать** и др. существительные, обозначающие конкретные предметы, употребляются в винительном падеже; абстрактные существительные и существительные, обозначающие часть предмета, - в родительном. Ср.: *ждать подругу, ждать помощи; хотеть конфету, хотеть независимости; искать книгу, искать поддержки; требовать необходимый документ, требовать справедливости.* 
Существительное **результат** относится к абстрактным. Поэтому употребление родительного падежа в вашем предложении соответствует правилу: "Я жду результатов тестирования".